Error 422 en php laravel con react.js
Estoy consumiendo una API de php laravel con React en una página llamada productos.js y tengo un botón llamado "Agregar producto", y cuando le doy click a este botón me salen estos errores:


Hola. Te recomiendo que revises esta guía sobre como preguntar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Aporta toda la información relevante que puedas para que podamos ayudarte mejor.
